# Spring Security multiple entry points - login process URL not found

Tags: spring-security

I rewrite the security configuration class from [this](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-and-spring-security-4-integration-example/) tutorial.

I try to enter the entries without login, the server redirect to the login page well, but submit the user credentials to login processing URL return page not found. How should I fix it?

My Spring Security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    ublic static class MobileSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .antMatcher("/mobile/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("MOBILE")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/mobile_login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/mobile_login_processing_url")
                    .usernameParameter("ssoId")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/mobile/menu")
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/mobile_logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/mobile_login?logout")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied")
                    .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(authenticationEntryPoint(), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/mobile/**"));
        }

        @Bean
        Public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(){
            return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/mobile_login");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/web/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/web_login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/web_login_processing_url")
                    .usernameParameter("ssoId")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/web/list")
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/web_login?logout")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
            "remember-me", userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
        return tokenBasedservice;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
        return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your login processing URL `/mobile_login_processing_url` is unavailable.

You configured a `formLogin`, which adds a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` for a `HttpSecurity`, see [`FormLoginConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/FormLoginConfigurer.html):

> The following Filters are populated
>
> - `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

but your `HttpSecurity`is restricted to the pattern `/mobile/**`, see [`HttpSecurity#antMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#antMatcher-java.lang.String-):

> Allows configuring the `HttpSecurity` to only be invoked when matching the provided ant pattern.

so with URL `/mobile_login_processing_url` the `HttpSecurity`is not invoked and therefore the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is never applied. Without this filter, the form login is not processible, see [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html):

> Processes an authentication form submission.

You have to change your login processing URL to `/mobile/mobile_login_processing_url`. See your modified configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(1)
ublic static class MobileSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .antMatcher("/mobile/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("MOBILE")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/mobile_login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/mobile/mobile_login_processing_url")
                .usernameParameter("ssoId")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/mobile/menu")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/mobile_logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/mobile_login?logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied")
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(authenticationEntryPoint(), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/mobile/**"));
    }

    @Bean
    Public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(){
        return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/mobile_login");
    }
}
```